# Error in installing moodle

Tags: installation, moodle

I am facing error while install moodle on my local server.
The error shows

```
Debug info: Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table'
[array (
)]
Error code: dmlreadexception
```

Stack trace:

```
line 474 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_read_exception thrown
line 1088 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
line 1527 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql()
line 332 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->get_record_sql()
line 308 of /lib/ddl/mysql_sql_generator.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->is_compressed_row_format_supported()
line 542 of /lib/ddl/database_manager.php: call to mysql_sql_generator->getAddFieldSQL()
line 74 of /mod/data/db/upgrade.php: call to database_manager->add_field()
line 726 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to xmldb_data_upgrade()
line 432 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_plugins_modules()
line 1742 of /lib/upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_plugins()
line 677 of /admin/index.php: call to upgrade_noncore()
```

I am using php 7.02, mysql 5.7.19 and moodle 3.0.10

Answer (score 1):

Open your mysql installation folder then go to bin folder, then open `my.ini` and

Add this following line

```
show_compatibility_56=ON
```

Comment: I'm not the question's author, but I was with the same problem and your answer helped me a lot! It worked! Thank you so much, man! God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter in terminal and put this comand

   ```
   sudo apt install apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php
   ```
2. Put this comand next

   ```
   sudo apt install graphviz aspell ghostscript clamav php-pspell php-curl php-gd php-intl php-mysql php-xml php-xmlrpc php-ldap php-zip php-soap php-mbstring
   ```
3. Download moodle
4. Extract it and enter a directory terminal

   ```
   cd ..
   ```
5. put this comand in that terminal

   ```
   sudo cp -R Moodle /var/www/html/
   ```
6. Then we will put this comand

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/moodledata
   ```
7. We will add permissions to the directory

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data /var/moodledata
   ```
8. Again

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 777 /var/moodledata
   ```
9. We will change the permissions of the moodle directory

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/moodle
   ```
10. We will prepare the database

    ```
    sudo mysql -u root -p
    ```
11. When we are connected to the database, we run these commands

    ```
    CREATE DATABASE moodle DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    create user'moodledude'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'changeMeAsap!'; 
    GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,DROP,INDEX,ALTER ON moodle.* TO 'moodledude'@'localhost';
    ```
12. Exist the mysql shell
13. Paste the config into the file you open with

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/www/html/moodle/config.php
    ```
14. Change the vars in `php.ini`:

    ```
    sudo nano /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini and change de vars
    ```

Comment: Making every file in `/var/moodledata` *writable* and even worse ***executable*** via `chmod 777 /var/moodledata` is a ***VERY BAD IDEA™*** and introduces a security nightmare. Are you sure these are the required permissions?